# YShout 5: Function Unserialize Error

Tags: php, serialization

Bought YShout and have been running on my webserver for some time now. Support isn't answering any emails in a long time. I keep getting unserialize errors that kill the chat box.

Error: There appears to be a problem: unserialize() Error at offset 65537 of 86434 bytes. File: filestorage.class.php Line 36.

Here is the function with line 36 in it.

```
function load() {
    if (($contents = $this->read($this->path)) == null)
    return $this->resetArray();
    return unserialize($contents);///////////line 36
}
```

here seems to be the line in the log file that is generating the error message, 65537 seems to be located right at the "a" in "uia:2:" in the string.

```
i:251;a:6:{s:8:"nickname";s:7:"TestUser";s:7:"message";s:30:"when he's online ask him";s:9:"timestamp";d:1373857811.6403610706329345703125;s:5:"admin";b:0;s:3:"uia:2:{s:4:"info";a:1:{s:15:"latestTimestamp";i:-1;}s:5:"posts";a:0:{}}ip";s:12:"76.174.54.75";}}
```

Not really sure how YShout works, but I'm getting this error more than once a day now. I have to delete the log file, then YShout creates a new log from scratch and all is well. But until I delete the log causing problems no one can use the chat window.

Ideal solution would be to fix this and figure out whats going on. Secondary solution would be to rename the log file causing the error. This would cause YShout to create a new log file to use and we would have a history of the log that contained the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message appearing when I was messing with the log file. If you add or remove characters from a message you'll end up with this error. But altering characters won't cause any trouble. So that means that YShout is storing message lengths in the log file.

Look at this line:

```
s:30:"when he's online ask him";
```

's' states that 30 characters are being used, but your message is only 24 characters long. Try changing it to 24 and the problem should be fixed.